# New image() .src pass variable to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable from evercookie to PHP using New Image() but i am a total novice at Javascript and cant seem to get it working.

This is the script i am using

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

ec.get("uinwish", function(value) {
   var img  = new Image();
   img.src = "http://www.mjyserver.com/trackclick?d=" + value;
   return false;
)}

</script>
```

Comment: I think you'll bet better response here if you add some more context, and an actual question.  We know nothing of they type of data you're sending, or what you want to use it for, or even the basic flow control it's going through.

Comment: what variable? what php? what is "evercookie" ? how can anyone guess what you are trying to do from info offered?

Comment: in your code you have misplaced end parent and curly brace it should be `});` because you close function and then get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On load is loaded only if "http://www.myserver.com/trackclick?d=" is actually an image that can be displayed. If you want to call php script why don't you all $.get jquery function

```
ec.get("uinwish", function(value) {
   $.get('http://www.myserver.com/trackclick?d=' + value, function() {
      // do something when php script is loaded
   });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: "On load is loaded only if `URL` is actually an image" ORLY? Open console and try it.